# plotting a function having different equations in different intervals of x in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot y as a function of x. In each x interval the function changes. My code is the following. I end up with an empty graph. Any idea?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl 

x=np.arange(0,10,11)
y=np.arange(0,10,11)

for i in range (0,len(x)):
   if x>5.:
      y=5.
   if x>3. and x<5.:
      y=x**2
   if x>0. and x<3.:
      y=2.
   i+=1


pl.plot(x,y)
pl.xlim([-3.,7.])
pl.ylim([-3.,7.]) 
pl.xlabel('Social Interaction')
pl.ylabel('Color/Hue')
pl.title('Bifurcation Diagram')
pl.show()
```

Comment: maybe you have to use `x[i]` and `y[i]` in `for` loop.

Comment: btw: why do you use `i+=1` ? if you need to skip some elements you can use `range(0, len(x), 2)`

Comment: `for` already increments `i`. `y` is a list. If you assign single value (`y=5.`) you lose list. Add `print(y)` before `plot` to see what you have in that variable.

Comment: Okay so in case the equation is y=5 how can I translate that into my code. I got the point and you're right but in the same time I took y=np.arange line out and I got an error saying that I haven't defined y. It should be a simple code but I am missing on something here...

Comment: `x=arange(0,10,11)` creates list with one element - zero.  Maybe you have wrong `step` (last argument in `arange`).

Comment: x=0  doesn't meet any `if` so you don't create `y`

Answer (score 0):

A good procedure with loops is always to try to perform diagnostics by printing out the values.  If you did that here, you would see that `x` has only one element.  That's because `np.arange(0, 10, 11)` means start at `0`, end at `10`, and take steps of `11`.  Because taking a step of `11` immediately goes past the end of `10`, there is only a single element in x, which is `x = array([0])`.  I'm not sure what you're looking for here.

A few quick notes: you don't need the decimal for comparisons in python, i.e. `x > 5` is fine, instead of `x > 5.`; the `range` function increments `i` automatically, so you don't need the `i += 1` --- it actually doesn't do anything here; finally, both `range` and `np.arange` default to starting at `0` so you don't need to include that (i.e. you can use `np.arange(10)` instead of `np.arange(0,10)`.

As you are iterating over `x` in the for-loop, you aren't looking at individual elements of the `x` and `y` arrays -- you are looking at the entire arrays.  If you want to look at single values at a time, you have to index the arrays with `x[i]` and `y[i]`, so you could do something like:

```
x = np.arange(10)  # this gives `array([0, 1, 2, ..., 9])`
y = np.arange(10)

for i in range (0,len(x)):
   if x[i] > 5:
      y[i] = 5
   if x[i] > 3 and x[i] < 5:
      y[i] = x[i]**2
   if x[i] > 0 and x[i] < 3:
      y[i] = 2
```

You can make this a bit faster and cleaner using more advanced array indexing.  If you do a comparison with a numpy array, it gives you an array of booleans showing where the comparison is true or false:

```
>>> x > 5
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You can also use an array of booleans like this as the index for another array, what it does is it prints the values where the booleans are true, for example:

```
>>> x[x > 5]
array([6, 7, 8, 9])
```

So you can use this to set `y` how you want:

```
>>> y[x > 5] = 5
>>> y
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

You can use the boolean `&` operator to combine criteria:

```
>>> inds = (x > 3) & (x < 5)
>>> y[inds] = x[inds]**2
>>> y
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 16,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5])
```